# after installing nvm getting lots of compile errors

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, package.json, tsc

for another project I am working on I installed nvm for windows, on my project #1 I didn't have any tsconfig.json file, and just did `tsc index.ts --sourceMap`.

I was happy as a puppy, but since nvm installed (which suggested I delete my local previously installed Node folder - i followed that suggestion). I am getting loads of errors

```
controller/game.ts(165,45): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Player[]'.
controller/http_server.ts(2,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'.
controller/http_server.ts(50,17): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
index.ts(7,12): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
index.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
```

and my tests (mocha) result in even more errors

```
test/test.ts(10,1): error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.
test/test.ts(12,5): error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.
```

here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myProj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.14"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^7.1.1"
  }
}
```

I am a bit reluctant to define a tsconfig with all that pain - but if I'll have to do this - I will

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggested, you have to install the typescript compiler for that specified package like npm install --save-dev @types/node and etc.